# Expand all nested tables from loaded XML file

Tags: xml, nested, powerquery

I am using the function ExpandAll to expand all tables recursively from a loaded XML file.

Function is:

```
let
    // http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/
    //Define function taking two parameters - a table and an optional column number 
    Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) =>
    let
     //If the column number is missing, make it 0
     ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,
     //Find the column name relating to the column number
     ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},
     //Get a list containing all of the values in the column
     ColumnContents = Table.Column(TableToExpand, ColumnName),
     //Iterate over each value in the column and then
     //If the value is of type table get a list of all of the columns in the table
     //Then get a distinct list of all of these column names
     ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, 
                        each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
     //Append the original column name to the front of each of these column names
     NewColumnNames = List.Transform(ColumnsToExpand, each ColumnName & "." & _),
     //Is there anything to expand in this column?
     CanExpandCurrentColumn = List.Count(ColumnsToExpand)>0,
     //If this column can be expanded, then expand it
     ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCurrentColumn 
                         then 
                         Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, 
                                ColumnsToExpand, NewColumnNames) 
                         else 
                         TableToExpand,
     //If the column has been expanded then keep the column number the same, otherwise add one to it
     NextColumnNumber = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then ActualColumnNumber else ActualColumnNumber+1,
     //If the column number is now greater than the number of columns in the table
     //Then return the table as it is
     //Else call the ExpandAll function recursively with the expanded table
     OutputTable = if NextColumnNumber>(Table.ColumnCount(ExpandedTable)-1) 
                        then 
                        ExpandedTable 
                        else 
                        ExpandAll(ExpandedTable, NextColumnNumber)
    in
     OutputTable
in
    Source
```

When calling the function with

```
let
    //Load XML file
    Source = Xml.Tables(File.Contents(oldFilePath)),
    //Call the ExpandAll function to expand all columns
    Output = ExpandAll(Source)
in
    Output
```

I get an expression error

> Cannot convert value "" to type Table.

How do I skip such blank values?

[image]

please see above code, error message and screenshots

Comment: change the function to be direct access on the Source file and see which step is failing. Once you tell us that, and show what the raw data looks like, might be able to help

Comment: might as well credit the original source for the function Chris Webb's blog @ http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/

Comment: Ah, that would explain why he did not use `??` instead of `if null then` - wasn't in M-Code in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, thanks for sharing your code, I was looking for it.

I got the same issue and resolved adding one step to your code:

```
    ...
    ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},

    **ReplaceEMPTY = Table.ReplaceValue(TableToExpand,"",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{ColumnName}),**

     //Get a list containing all of the values in the column
     ColumnContents = Table.Column(**ReplaceEMPTY**, ColumnName)
     ...
```

The Function with this added on:

```
let
    // http://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2014/05/21/expanding-all-columns-in-a-table-in-power-query/
    //Define function taking two parameters - a table and an optional column number 
    Source = (TableToExpand as table, optional ColumnNumber as number) =>
    let
       //If the column number is missing, make it 0
       ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,
      //Find the column name relating to the column number
      ColumnName = Table.ColumnNames(TableToExpand){ActualColumnNumber},
      
      //ADDed to the original code to transform blank cells, now the Columns can be expanded as table
      ReplaceEMPTY = Table.ReplaceValue(TableToExpand,"",null,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{ColumnName}),**

      //Get a list containing all of the values in the column
      ColumnContents = Table.Column(ReplaceEMPTY,ColumnName),
      //Iterate over each value in the column and then
      //If the value is of type table get a list of all of the columns in the table
      //Then get a distinct list of all of these column names
      ColumnsToExpand = List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(ColumnContents, 
                    each if _ is table then Table.ColumnNames(_) else {}))),
       //Append the original column name to the front of each of these column names
       NewColumnNames = List.Transform(ColumnsToExpand, each ColumnName & "." & _),
       //Is there anything to expand in this column?
       CanExpandCurrentColumn = List.Count(ColumnsToExpand)>0,
       //If this column can be expanded, then expand it
       ExpandedTable = if CanExpandCurrentColumn 
                     then 
                     Table.ExpandTableColumn(TableToExpand, ColumnName, 
                            ColumnsToExpand, NewColumnNames) 
                     else 
                     TableToExpand,
       //If the column has been expanded then keep the column number the same, otherwise add one to it
       NextColumnNumber = if CanExpandCurrentColumn then ActualColumnNumber else ActualColumnNumber+1,
       //If the column number is now greater than the number of columns in the table
       //Then return the table as it is
       //Else call the ExpandAll function recursively with the expanded table
       OutputTable = if NextColumnNumber>(Table.ColumnCount(ExpandedTable)-1) 
                    then 
                    ExpandedTable 
                    else 
                    ExpandAll(ExpandedTable, NextColumnNumber)
    in
       OutputTable
in
    Source
```

Hope it works for you!!!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: just edit, How is it?

Comment: you can simplify the line `ActualColumnNumber = if (ColumnNumber=null) then 0 else ColumnNumber,` to `ActualColumnNumber = ColumnNumber ?? 0`, (side note, the original parenthesis are redundant, you can drop them)